# How to modify a specific set of values in a nested dictionary with multiple keys in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to modify a certain category of values in a nested dictionary with multiple keys. Specifically I want to set all "Bmax" values equal to 2.
The original dictionary is:

```
UNIT_TASKS = {
        ('Heater',    'Heating', 'Pablo')   : {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax': 100},
        ('Reactor_1', 'Reaction_1', 'Juan'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  80}, 
        ('Reactor_1', 'Reaction_2', 'Pedro'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  80}, 
        ('Reactor_1', 'Reaction_3', 'Pablo'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  80}, 
        ('Reactor_2', 'Reaction_1', 'Pablo'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  80},
        ('Reactor_2', 'Reaction_2', 'Juan'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  80}, 
        ('Reactor_2', 'Reaction_3', 'Pablo'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  80},
        ('Still',     'Separation', 'Pablo'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax': 200}, 
        ('Heater',    'Heating', 'Juan')   : {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax': 300}, 
        }
```

The one that I want to get is:

```
UNIT_TASKS = {
        ('Heater',    'Heating', 'Pablo')   : {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax': 2},
        ('Reactor_1', 'Reaction_1', 'Juan'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  2}, 
        ('Reactor_1', 'Reaction_2', 'Pedro'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  2}, 
        ('Reactor_1', 'Reaction_3', 'Pablo'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  2}, 
        ('Reactor_2', 'Reaction_1', 'Pablo'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  2},
        ('Reactor_2', 'Reaction_2', 'Juan'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  2}, 
        ('Reactor_2', 'Reaction_3', 'Pablo'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  2},
        ('Still',     'Separation', 'Pablo'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax': 2}, 
        ('Heater',    'Heating', 'Juan')   : {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax': 2}, 
        }
```

I tried with the following code lines:

```
TASKS = set([i for (j,i,k) in UNIT_TASKS])
UNITS = set([j for (j,i,k) in UNIT_TASKS])
NAMES = set([k for (j,i,k) in UNIT_TASKS])


UNITS_DIC = {j: set() for j in UNITS}
for (j,i,k) in UNIT_TASKS:
    UNITS_DIC[j].add(i)

NAMES_DIC = {k: set() for k in NAMES}
for (j,i,k) in UNIT_TASKS:
    NAMES_DIC[k].add(i)

TASKS_DIC = {i: set() for i in TASKS}
for (j,i,k) in UNIT_TASKS:
    TASKS_DIC[i].add(k)


for i in UNITS:
    for j in UNITS_DIC[i]:
        for k in NAMES_DIC[j]:
            UNIT_TASKS[(i,j,k)]['Bmax'] =  2
```

But Python returns error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try more simply:

```
for k, d in UNIT_TASKS.items():  # iterates over key, value pairs in dictionary
  d['Bmax'] = 2                  # Update Bmax in dictionary
```

**Result**

*UNIT_TASKS*

```
{('Heater', 'Heating', 'Juan'): {'Bmax': 2, 'Bmin': 0},
 ('Heater', 'Heating', 'Pablo'): {'Bmax': 2, 'Bmin': 0},
 ('Reactor_1', 'Reaction_1', 'Juan'): {'Bmax': 2, 'Bmin': 0},
 ('Reactor_1', 'Reaction_2', 'Pedro'): {'Bmax': 2, 'Bmin': 0},
 ('Reactor_1', 'Reaction_3', 'Pablo'): {'Bmax': 2, 'Bmin': 0},
 ('Reactor_2', 'Reaction_1', 'Pablo'): {'Bmax': 2, 'Bmin': 0},
 ('Reactor_2', 'Reaction_2', 'Juan'): {'Bmax': 2, 'Bmin': 0},
 ('Reactor_2', 'Reaction_3', 'Pablo'): {'Bmax': 2, 'Bmin': 0},
 ('Still', 'Separation', 'Pablo'): {'Bmax': 2, 'Bmin': 0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
for k, v in UNIT_TASKS.items():
    v.update(dict(Bmax=2))
```

update method, overwrites if keys exist and adds the key value pair if not.